# nginx redirecting images with 302 to 404

Tags: nginx

For whatever reason unknown to me nginx is redirecting png and ico extensions to 404 even though the files exist:

What am i doing wrong here:

```
index login.php index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~* \.(css|js|png|woff2|woff|ttf|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri.php;
}

error_page 404 404;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks for your time I am an idiot :)

[root@localhost tpl]# find -name sort_both.png
./plugins/datatables/images/sort_both.png
[root@localhost tpl]# grep sort_both.png -Rl *
plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css
plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Was refering relative ../images vs images/